# How to create a request from only a URL string and supply query parameters in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am storing URLs in a database and I would like to have certain requests pull these URL stings and then request the data. I can make the requests, but have not been able to figure out how to add query parameters to the request.

```
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory

factory = APIRequestFactory()
url = '/some/nice/url/'
func, args, kwargs = resolve(url)
view = func.cls.as_view({'get': 'list'})
request = factory.get(url)
request.user = get_current_user()
response = view(request, **{'item': 1})  # <- this query param has no effect
response.render()

json.loads(response.content.decode("utf-8"))['results']
```

This does return a response, but the query params I supply have no effect.

Also, [this ticket](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3825) provides some clues, but no solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Both the queryset and the serializer are accessible, so all that is needed was to combine them like this:

```
func, args, kwargs = resolve(url)
queryset = func.cls.queryset.filter(**filter_dict)
serializer = func.cls.serializer_class

return serializer(queryset, many=True).data
```